# Want to populate "New Message" window using Extended MAPI in C++

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

I want to populate Outlook "New Message" window programmatically with To and Cc fields populated. Does the Extended MAPI have API for it? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Amol S

Answer (score 0):

Of course. `IMessage::ModifyRecipients(MODRECIP_ADD, ...)`.

Comment: Thank you for reply Dmity.   I also want to populate the outlook  "New Message" window. I have created the message and also added the recipients using the above method. Now how to set this message on Outlook New Message window? below is the message i have created =>    CComPtr<IMessage> mapiMessage;
        hRes = spInboxFolder->CreateMessage(NULL, 0, &mapiMessage);   mapiMessage->ModifyRecipients(MODRECIP_ADD, addrList);

Comment: Also please let me know how to open the outlook "New Message" window programmatically.

Comment: `IMAPISession.PrepareForm` / `IMAPISession.ShowForm` to display the message modally. Note that the MAPI forms are implemented by outlook.exe, so if Outlook is displaying the message, you might as well use OOM either to display the mesage (`Namespace.GetItemFromID `/ `MailItem.Display`) or even create the message using OOM - no MAPI is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dmitry. I am able to populate the "New Message" window using PrepareForm & ShowForm. But sometimes getting the "Could not load the one or more attachments" error while loading the "New Message" window and then after that when click on send button to send message it wont allow giving error "The operation failed. The messaging interfaces have returned an unknown error. If the problem persists, restart Outlook." Any pointer on this. Rest all is working fine.

Comment: I don't know - hard to say without seeing all the code and running it in the debugger.